# Vsto: How to deactivate an addin

Tags: c#, vsto

I built some addin for Excel, I use some webservices, and I'd like to know if there is a way to desactivate my addin if my webservices don't work?
So I have to add something like:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(!isalive())
    {
       turn off the addin
    }

}
```

but what could I add to turn them off?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa662931(v=office.11).aspx) info I believe that you have to set `Connect` property to true to activate and to false to deactivate.

```
YourAddin.Connect = true;
```